# R function to write results in to a csv file

Tags: r, string, function

Hi I have created this R function two do some operation and store the results into separate files.

```
x1=rnorm(100,0,1)
x2=rnorm(100,0,1)
dataaa=data.frame(x1,x2)
func1=function(dataaa,name1,name2)
{
  xqr=dataaa[,1]^2
  xcube=dataaa[,1]^3
write.csv(xqr,"name1.csv")
write.csv(xcube,"name2.csv")

}

func1(dataaa,xr,xc)
```

The function works well. But the file name didnt change. i.e the names of the two csv files should be xr.csv and xc.csv. But it was saved as name1.csv and name2.csv.

How to modify this function so that I can get the correct file names?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
func1=function(dataaa,name1,name2)
{
  xqr=dataaa[,1]^2
  xcube=dataaa[,1]^3
  write.csv(xqr, paste0(name1,".csv"))
  write.csv(xcube, paste0(name2,".csv"))

}
```

Comment: try func1(dataaa,"xr","xc")